# Custom listview alignment in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am make custom list view xml file. Xml file having Two images and four TextView

Here My xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgproperty"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/StreetName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgproperty"
    android:text="Street Name:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstlocation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/StreetName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/StreetName"
    android:text="Location:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstsquare"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lstlocation"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/StreetName"
    android:text="SquareFootage:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstprice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lstsquare"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/StreetName"
    android:text="Price:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imglike"
     android:layout_width="30dip"
     android:layout_height="30dip"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
     android:src="@drawable/star1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here my output** 
[image]

**i want to set first image width is full screen of the Listview row **

Please Suggest Me how i can Set Image width Full  of listview row

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` attribute to the first `ImageView` XML as follows...

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgproperty"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 0):

set the android:layout_height="80dp" of a relative layout try this.
its not compelsory to set 80dp give any dp size which u feel correct

here is the output

[image: output]